# Custom naming convention for image sequence

Tags: rendering, video

how do I render out an image sequence with my own custom naming convention for eg. Abc_00000001 or something....

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `#` for the digits of the numbering in the file name.

Example (Windows path):

- in the *Output Properties* tab, in section *Output* enter the file path `C:\animation1\Abc_########`. Check *Saving* `[X]` *File Extensions* if you want to append the file extension (like *.png*).

The created files then will be named as *Abc_00000001.png, Abc_00000002.png, Abc_00000003.png*, ...

Comment: Is it possible to save the exported file as the same name as the image sequence file? I.e. frame #27 = Example27.jpg, and the export filename is Example27?

Comment: What do you mean by "exported file"?

Comment: My image sequence has 250 images with unique filenames, and I want to keep these filenames when the animation frames are rendered. Is it possible to include the filename of the image sequence file(s) in the filename of each exported animation frame?

Comment: any thoughts on that?